# "Send an Wait for Approval" inside a "Apply to each" will never end

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow

I have "Send an wait for approval" which will Assign To a list of users >> and the furst user response should end the action. here is my high level steps:-
[image]

setting inside the Apply to Each:-
[image]

setting inside the "Send and wait for approval":-
[image]

Remaining actions inside the "Apply to Each":-
[image]

but currently when the flow get run >> and the first user response >> the flow will keep running and the loop will never ends... any advice? should i re-order my actions? seems the loop will wait for all user to response for it to get ended?

Thank

Answer (score 5):

Your current flow is creating a separate approval request for each member of the group instead of sending a single approval request to all members.

I think you'll need to create a string variable and append the `mail` property and a `semicolon` for each group member. You would then add this variable to the Assigned To field in your start and wait for approval step.

[image]